# Find an intersecting value for each row and column in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, sumproduct

I have monthly data in rows in column A. I also have monthly data in headers from column B to Column G. In Column H i have current month populated for all rows. I would like to display the value where, for example if the month in row is Jan and current month is Mar, then find the value where Jan and Mar intersect and do this for all rows. I tried using the following formula in Column J but it only gives the first value when it works. The result in Column I is desired. Attached is the picture for clarity.

[image]

`=INDEX(B1:H2,MATCH(A2,$A$1:A2,0),MATCH(A2,$B$1:H2,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with SUMPRODUCT.

I made a fake dataset with **different values** than the ones you show, so i could test properly if changing Current month would work.

It works even if column `CurrentMonth` holds different months

[image]

My formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$G$1=H2);B2:G2)
```

This is how it works:

1. `--($B$1:$G$1=H2)` will return an array of 1 and 0 if range `B1:G1` is equal to current month in that row. So in case `CurrentMonth=Mar` then it will return `{0;0;1;0;0;0}`
2. With SUMPRODUCT we multiply previous array by range `B:G` in current row, so for row 2, it would be `B2:G2`. So as example, it would be `{0;0;1;0;0;0} * {1;2;3;4;5;6} = {0;0;3;0;0;0}` and we sum up this array, getting 3

Answer (score 2):

just use INDEX with one MATCH:

```
=INDEX(B2:G2,,MATCH(H2,$B$1:$G$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!, both answers were terrific and worked exactly as i desired